# Replacing child record columns during SELECT with JOIN operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view, replace

I am trying to create a view by join two tables together which is by no means difficult. But there is a but.

I basically have two tables. One of them stores associations between items and tags and the other stores tags in parent-child form (8 parents with 4-6 children each).

Allow me to illustrate starting with my item association table:

```
AssociationId | ItemId | TagId
------------------------------
1             | 2      | 1
2             | 10     | 2
3             | 3      | 1
4             | 5      | 7
...
```

And my tags table:

```
TagId | ParentId | Name
------------------------------
1     | NULL     | abc sds
2     | 1        | sjdksd as
3     | 1        | djfsd dfs d
4     | NULL     | ujkjsd as
...
```

As you can see each parent can be found by decorating queries with `ParentId IS NULL`.

```
SELECT ITA.AssociationId, ITA.ItemId, ITA.TagId, T.Name as TagName
FROM Item_Tag_Association AS ITA
INNER JOIN Tags AS T
ON T.TagId = ITA.TagId
WHERE T.ParentId IS NULL
```

If I was to join both tables on `TagId` with `ParentId IS NULL` I would find all items with parent tags.

If I was to join both tables on `TagId` with `ParentId IS NOT NULL` I would find all items with child tags.

But what I actually want is a list of items and tags where child tags are replaced by their parent tags.

Using above example the result would look something like this:

```
AssociationId | ItemId | TagId | TagName
----------------------------------------
1             | 2      | 1     | abc sds
2             | 10     | 1     | abc sds
3             | 3      | 1     | abc sds
4             | 5      | 7     | ysdasjdhas
...
```

As for the reason why I want to do this is so that I could get a count of how many times a specific parent tag (or child of that parent) has been associated with an item. And as you guessed it by now each child should contribute to its parent.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemId, TagId, TagName, COUNT(ItemId) OVER (PARTITION BY TagId) AS Count
FROM vw_My_View
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2. All constructive suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Tanner as per my question last table illustrates what desired result would look like.

Comment: ok, i thought that was an intermediate step before the counting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you only have one level in your parent/child hierarchy you could do an extra left join from tags to itself to find parent if it exists like this:

```
SELECT ita.AssociationId, ita.ItemId, ISNULL(parent.TagId, t.TagId), ISNULL(parent.Name, t.Name) AS TagName
FROM Item_Tags_Association ita
  JOIN Tags t ON ita.TagId = t.TagId
  LEFT JOIN Tags parent ON t.ParentId = parent.TagId
```

The first (inner) join can join to either a child tag or a parent tag. The left join will include the parent tag *if* the tag in association has a parent. 
The ISNULL will make sure the value from the second (left) join is used if not null, otherwise use the value from the first join.

If you prefer not dealing with [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=sql.105).aspx)(or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.105).aspx)) you could make use of a [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.105).aspx) and a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx) like this:

```
WITH ParentTags AS (SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE ParentId IS NULL)
SELECT ita.AssociationId, ita.ItemId, t.TagId, t.Name AS TagName
FROM ParentTags t
  JOIN Item_Tags_Association ita ON ita.TagId = t.TagId
UNION ALL 
SELECT ita.AssociationId, ita.ItemId, t.TagId, t.Name AS TagName
FROM ParentTags t
  JOIN Tags child ON t.TagId = child.ParentId
  JOIN Item_Tags_Association ita ON ita.TagId = child.TagId
```

Comment: @Iarsts you assumed correct that parent/child hierarchy will only have one level.

Comment: I can confirm that ``ISNULL`` solution is working but I don't yet understand how/why exactly. But the the use of ``ISNULL()`` is quite clever.

Comment: Tried adding an explanation to the post. Basically the left join is there to include the information from a parent tag _if_ it exists (if the tag in association has a parentid defined). The isnull is used to use the value from this parent tag if it is found, otherwise use the value from the first join (which would be to a tag without parentid -> which means it is the parent tag to begin with). A bit cumbersome explanation this, hope you understand.

Comment: The union/cte approach should also work, and is probably easier to read :)

Comment: @Iarsts union/cte approach is indeed easier to read and I confirm it as a working solution.

Comment: Because had a previous query before union/cte approach code SQL raised ``Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'...`` error. This was easily fixed with a semicolon ``;WITH...`` (just in case no one reads the error to the very end).

Comment: @Iarsts that pretty much sorted me out. Thank you very much.